# passing environment variable to a java class in command line

Tags: java

I have a necessity to read some properties from a file located in local `etc/myconfig-config/` folder. I need to give this file path in the command line. I have given it as mentioned below. But there is an error and it displays like

```
Error: Could not find or load main class test-tool.jar.
```

the command given is

```
java  -cp -DconfigDir=/etc/myconfig-config/ test-tool.jar 
service.ScriptGenerator $clinic_count $client_files_count
```

can anybody please help me to resolve this.

thanks

Comment: Note that you are wanting to read a property at runtime, not an environment (`System.getProperty("xxx")` vs `System.getenv("xxx")`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try giving following command,

```
java -DconfigDir=/etc/myconfig-config/ -cp test-tool.jar service.ScriptGenerator $clinic_count $client_files_count
```

Note that the given parameters should be accessed from code as follow:

```
System.getProperty("configDir")
```

Comment: It work Sathish but when I put System.getenv("configDir") it prints null. Could you give a solution to this.... thanks

Comment: Hi, use System.getProperty("configDir") insteadof getenv() method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sathish it works.... I ask this question if it is not a disturbance to u.  When I run it through IDE the   System.getenv("configDir")  works fine. But when i run it through terminal using above command the System.getProperty("configDir") working fine.. I cannot think why is this...

Comment: You are welcome Dilan, I did not get what is not working. Can you please explain? I'll try to help if i know the answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Try this command

**`export VARNAME='variable-value'`**

Then run your Java main class from the same command line.

Answer (score 1):

Your command should be like

```
java  -cp test-tool.jar -DconfigDir=/etc/myconfig-config/ service.ScriptGenerator $clinic_count $client_files_count
```