# How to put project Input resources outside of JAR like Lib folder

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I have project which takes Database SQL queries from text files under project folder. When building JAR file I want to put that scripts folder outside of JAR file, but Jar can Access that queries from scripts folder,

i.e., Like when we build JAR file with Netbeans *lib* folder for that JAR created separately as libraries
same thing I want with script folder but programs can take queries as Input from that folder.

I'm reading queries from text file because my project queries are of about 20 lines and it will change periodically, so I can't add it in actual Java program also I don't want to create DB Stored procedures for the result.
[I have shared my projects directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBuN6.png)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [passing environment variable to a java class in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30889478/passing-environment-variable-to-a-java-class-in-command-line)

Comment: you can specify the folder location with the -D flag then in your code take the folder location and load your sql files from it using a file reader

Comment: Its working if we put scripts folder and JAR file in same directory by normal use